# Flash of default style for questions

Tags: feature-request, design

There's a noticeable delay between when the question list starts to render and when the excluded or highlighted tag styles are applied, i.e., there's a flash of default style. Instead of waiting for the DOM to be ready to apply the styles, you could use `document.write()` to make an individual stylesheet like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .t-php, .t-javascript { /* highlight rules */ }
    .t-java { /* ignore rules */ }
</style>
```

This would still allow the list to be cached but make the rendering more smooth and hence the sites more usable.

Edit: The same can also be done with DOM methods.

Comment: hey, cool idea!